# How to make Nginx try_files ignore the port the server listens?

Tags: nginx, openvpn, port

I have a server running both OpenVPN and Nginx on port 443: I configured OpenVPN to run on 443 with the port-share option while Nginx runs on 4545.

All of this seems to work except the `try_files` directive.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

When I access a directory `https://mydomain.tld/directory`, instead of being redirected to `https://mydomain.tld/directory/`, I get `https://mydomain.tld:4545/directory/`. Of course, the port 4545 is blocked by my firewall and the connection fails.

How could I avoid Nginx to redirect to the port it listens using `try_files`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up `port_in_redirect off;` in your server configuration.

Comment: What do you do in the case where the original request is to a particular port (e.g. 8080), which is forwarded to the port nginx is serving on?